# Images in web browser are slightly blurred. How to disable it?

Tags: html, image, firefox, canvas

I'm making a game. Collisions in this game are based on color of pixel on canvas. I get color pixel and if it is for example red, player can't move.
Unfortunately in firefox images are remotely blurred. Pixels are fluently changed from white color to red. But I don't want that.
[image]
Any ideas how to answer to this problem?

Comment: is the image presented in it's original format?

Comment: Are you allowing your image to be scaled to the browser window size?  You may want to disallow that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called anti-aliasing and is a result of interpolating the image when re-sized (or sub-pixeling shapes, text and so forth). It's something the browser do internally.

You can however turn off this in more recent version of the browser.

Here is a test I made to see if this works in your browser and the difference between the modes (as in the picture below) - the bottom version should not be smoothed:

<kbd>**[ONLINE TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TYUUJ/)**</kbd>

[image]

Add this snippet to your CSS style sheet (may or may not work depending on browser):

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             // Older versions of FF
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          // FF 6.0+
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; // Webkit (non standard naming)
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            // OS X & Windows Opera (12.02+)
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;               // Possible future browsers.
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   // IE (non standard naming)
}
```

**Update:**
The [current form of the standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#image-rendering) (with status "*not ready for implementation*") specify `crisp-edges` and not `optimize-contrast` as possible future standard. CSS class above is updated with this to reflect this for the non-prefixed value.
*- end update -*

For webkit browsers you can disable image smoothing for the canvas element like this:

```
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

and for Mozilla:

```
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

(when this latter is available the CSS class is not necessary unless you scale the element itself which in any case should be avoided).

Comment: Much better, but not entirely. This is picture in GIMP (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59608446/Fora%20pytania/porownanie1.png) this is picture in Firefox (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59608446/Fora%20pytania/porownanie2.png). In firefox are still unwanted pixels :P