# Re-write javascript animation to prevent scaling/blurring in browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have limited scripting skills and am stuck trying to re-write a small script for an eLearning lesson animation.

With help, a few years ago (no longer available), ported an AS3 animation to JS. When the JS is tested/run in FF, IE or Chrome, it is blurry.

The script, from what little I can understand, is drawing in a canvas using 1x1 px rectangles for the animation. This is causing scaling, blurring and distortion.

I am not sure how to re-write the JavaScript for the canvas drawing so that it uses the correct size rectangles (8x8 pixels instead of 1x1 pixels)?

I think once that is changed from 1x1 to 8x8, then the canvas sizes in the script, index.html and style.css may need to be changed, to match (the final size should be 640X640)?

Any help appreciated with re-writing (I've tried everything I know, but no success).

Link (index.html, src.js, style.css):
https://elearningprojects.com/websample1/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas is just 80x80 pixels.
Your CSS is scaling it up to 640x480, meaning you just stretch the bitmap you're drawing to the canvas.
(this explains your blurriness)

The trick to achieving your scaling is here :

```
var scaleFactor = 10;
for(i = 0; i < 6400; i++)
{
    d = random()*256|0;
    val = array[d];
    viewbmd.fillStyle = "rgb(" + val + ", " + val + ", " + val + ")";
    //fillrect draws your "pixels", 
    viewbmd.fillRect(i%80*scaleFactor, (((i)/80)|0)*scaleFactor , scaleFactor, scaleFactor); 
}
```

In order to emulate drawing bix pixels, you multiply the x/y position of the rectangles you draw with the same number that determines their size (see scaleFactor).

In the example, i'm drawing "pixels" that are actually 10x10 "points".

This way, the initial picture is drawn correctly.

We run into trouble though, the second we hit `flipSomePixels`, because it just takes actual pixels from the bitmap we drew earlier, and starts flipping those, so we will need a similar trick to draw the updated fake pixel there.

**::update::**

Thanks to Ken, i got an idea on how to achieve this in an "easier" way.
We can draw the original 80x80 canvas off screen, and stretch that across a bigger canvas.

We still need to do away with the css canvas resizing though, because resizing the canvas element will still cause the blurry scaling to happen.
Instead, we make the canvas 640x640 and tell it to do crisp image rendering like this:

-css:

```
canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; 
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   
}
```

-html:

```
<canvas width="640" height="640"></canvas>
```

For a working example, see http://jsfiddle.net/QTvpe/10/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I appreciate your help. I thought that the canvas is 80X80, and scales to 640X640? I tried adding the new script (using scale = 8), but this did not solve the blurring. Sorry, not very skilled at this. Maybe, the problem is what you mentioned:"We run into trouble though, the second we hit flipSomePixels, because it just takes actual pixels from the bitmap we drew earlier, and starts flipping those, so we will need a similar trick to draw the updated fake pixel there." Not sure how to fix this. Still need help, please.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps i should have elaborated a bit more. The canvas is indeed tiny, and being scaled up (which looks hideous).
The best way to fix this, is to make the canvas itself bigger, not to scale the canvas, and to just draw bigger squares rather than individual pixels.

Comment: The code example i gave gives a rough explanation of how to do that

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunately, when I tried different combinations using the scaling, tried applying it also to flipSomePixels, got strange displays, but no success.

Comment: Hi, i updated the answer for you with an easier solution and a complete example. Good luck, happy programming, and keep learning! :)

Comment: Hi Timothy,I very much appreciate your and Ken's help. Am learning a lot! OK, now (after a few try's) got it to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried to view the animation using Chrome on an Android tablet: it automatically displays at full screen even though it is a 640X640 animation. I tried adding:function cancelFullscreen() {
  if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
    document.cancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
  }
}

cancelFullscreen();//But this does not fix it. Any way to display at 640X640?

Comment: that's pretty weird. fullscreen mode shouldn't happen unless we specifically ask for it.
Are you sure the problem is not just that the canvas is now bigger than the resolution of the android tablet?
640x640 *might* be bigger than it can show in a single go.

Comment: I added this to the HTML page, and it seems to work:<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you try to achieve as the images are vastly enlarged but, you can try to turn off anti-aliasing of the images. This will give you the 8-bit look from old days if that is what you're looking for.

```
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

and for Mozilla:

```
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Also see my related answer here for full context:
[Images in web browser are slightly blurred. How to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617254/images-in-web-browser-are-blurred-a-bit-how-to-fix-it/17618094#17618094)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. Helps me learn. I tried using these in the CSS. Makes the display very small (80X80). Needs to be 640X640 without blurring. Unfortunately, as a retired social worker with very limited scripting skills/understanding, no success trying to fix script someone else suggested 3 years ago. Have never gotten it to work correctly.

Comment: Am trying to use the newer HTML5, canvas for animation exercises for these eLearning lessons, converting them slowly from Flash, if possible. Can then be deployed on a wider range of devices: allows more people to view the lessons (which are designed to help them improve health). So, I'll keep trying. One day... :)

Comment: @user1134527 You will be fine! It takes an a-ha experience from time to time and then moving to next level, step by step. The longest path starts with a first step. ActionScript and JavaScript are very similar as they are both based on ECMAScript.

Comment: Yes, I've been using ECMA-262 in a program called Opus (DigitalWorkshop-UK), since 2004. A useful solution for this latest script, involving web page displays, scaling, browsers, however, has so far eluded me. Tried everything. No "a-ha" moments yet. BTW, even tried turning off the SmoothingEnabled (I read your other posting, as suggested) but this didn't solve the scaling/blurring issue. Not sure what to try next?

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware unfortunately, this does not work if you're scaling the canvas itself, it only works if you're scaling a bitmap inside the canvas, so it takes a bit more work (see http://jsfiddle.net/dqqem/ )

Comment: @TimothyGroote see the link I'm referring to in my answer (bottom line). There is a CSS class you can apply to the element itself. Basically what you do in the fiddle. :-)