# Does canvas corrupt base64 data?

Tags: html, canvas, base64

I'm building a icon-manager as a webservice where the icons are stored as base64 blobs (svgs and pngs) in a database.

I would like to render the icons on a clients html5 canvas where the client can manipulate (hues/color replacement/redrawing it) it and then send it back to the database.

My concern with this layout is that canvas will corrupt the image. **I have noticed in past experiments with the canvas that it tends to smoothen out images**, e.g. soften pixelated edges. This would be a disaster in this case. Some of the icons are tiny 16x16 images and after a couple of tours through the canvas I fear they would be ruined.

**A. Does the canvas element corrupt image data?**

**B. If so - is there some way to avoid this?**

My third option is to let the user download a image-map and edit that through a desktop application - then upload it. This would be major drag on the workflow. The database contains 3336 icons per theme-set.

Comment: No, I am more concerned with what I now know is anti-aliasing. I think it's possible to turn off in some browsers. Since it's not possible in all browsers the image might get ruined. I will choose another strategy.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to provide the wrong link - should be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617254/images-in-web-browser-are-blurred-a-bit-how-to-fix-it/17618094#17618094

Comment: Hm, I hope this will do it. It would speed up the work flow immensly. Thx :)