# Blurry to pixelated custom Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm seeking to create a custom fade in with jQuery or JS. I'd like the fade to be exaggerated and go from very blurry, to pixelated, to then the clear crisp image. On page load, one time.

This is for one image. Yes, tradditionaly done via making an animated gif I suppose. But can I write the effect with jQuery?

On page load. Grabbing the image `#div` >

> Image loads blurry > then pixelates in > and then the clear original HQ image resolves.

[image]

Comment: Is this for one specific image (e.g. making yourself an animated gif based on that image)?  Or an effect you want to use with lots of images?

Comment: What have you tried? You can do this by using the `canvas` element to apply image filters.

Comment: Blur can be achieved with CSS3 but the pixelation can't be done.

Comment: You could create the three static assets, position: absolute them over eachother and then crossfade them with jQuery.

Comment: You could adapt what [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) does; if you want the pixelation it should be even faster. *edit* actually if you *just* want to go from pixelated to, well, un-pixelated I think it's a lot simpler.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/

Comment: There's a plug-in that could help with the pixelation. Might not be the exact option you're looking for, but couldn't hurt to check out the source code if you need to modify it. http://close-pixelate.desandro.com/ Combine this with blur.js or another method and you're set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Demo snapshot]

To pixelate an image you can use canvas directly in a simple way like this (here assuming  image has already been loaded):

```
/// get a block size (see demo for this approach)
size = blocks.value / 100,
w = canvas.width * size,
h = canvas.height * size;

/// draw the original image at a fraction of the final size
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

/// turn off image aliasing (see comment below)
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;  /// future

/// enlarge the minimized image to full size    
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

**[Here is an online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/QznT7/)**.

You can use the slider at the bottom to see various sizes and the speed which would be needed for your transition (use Chrome to see live update when moving the slider) or simply hit the animate button.

As we turn off interpolation (image smoothing) the new enlarged image will appear blocky. This method is also faster than most other approached mainly due to image smoothing can now be turned off in the major browsers.

See this answer for a more complete instruction on how to turn smoothing off in most browsers:
[Images in web browser are slightly blurred. How to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617254/images-in-web-browser-are-blurred-a-bit-how-to-fix-it/17618094#17618094)

The last `drawImage` will use a clipped part of the source (here: canvas itself). See [here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to use this method.

As for blur effect I would recommend you to pre-blur the image as this process has a large overhead and the pause will be noticeable on most common computers.

In case you still want to blur the image "live" you can use this stack-blur:
http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Close Pixelate](https://github.com/desandro/close-pixelate) by David DeSandro. [The Pixelator](http://goo.gl/mFwChW) is a good example of it in action.