# Javascript Canvas upscale very low FPS

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, canvas

I have made a very simple game using canvas, i used 480x320 as my resolution, then i used CSS to scale things up to fit all sizes

```
canvas{height: 100% width:100%}
html{height: 100% width:100%}
```

I am using the Intel XDK for development

The game is very smooth on mobile phones and tablets up to HD resolution, but it goes very slow in FullHD phones and tablets, Is there any way to upscale without losing too much FPS, i tried making the same game in higher resolution then down scaling which makes it even more slow.

Comment: Try using a webworker to do all your computations instead of running it in the main thread. maybe that will help the fps issues a bit. also if your target is android, please... make an app, it will work much smoother. Then you can give users an option, install app or play in browser, but the app will be faster.

Comment: turn off interpolation. I am  not sure if these are supported on android, but you could give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617254/images-in-web-browser-are-blurred-a-bit-how-to-fix-it